# Save estimation data results in dynare

Tags: matlab, estimation, mcmc

I'm working with [Dynare](https://www.dynare.org/#). I'm estimating (not only simulating, but estimating) a DSGE model. The problem is that I don't know how to save the results of the Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) results that Dynare generates "automatically". I imagine there's a line of code in Dynare that allows it, however I don't know it.

I've already tried some possible lines, but they didn't work:

```
posterior_sampler_options('save_tmp_file','data_mh_tmp_blck');
```

and

```
dynasave(data) a y z;
```